# How can you show attribute values in 3DView

Tags: python, 3d-view

You can display indices and some measurements, but it'd be great to be able to visualize any attribute the same way.

Specifically I'd want to see Face strength values (__mod_weightednormals_faceweight).
Preferably in color like how Face Orientation is done, but i'd settle for just numbers next to faces